# java mail store type "imap" vs "imaps"

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the following code to validate an email programatically.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");

store.connect(host, user, password);
if(store.isConnected()){
      System.out.println("true");
 }
```

currently it throws an exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection dropped by server?;
nested exception is:
java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:670)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at com.**.channel.type.IMAPValidator.fetch(IMAPValidator.java:23)
at com.**.channel.type.IMAPValidator.main(IMAPValidator.java:47)
```

However if i use

```
emailSession.getStore("imaps");
```

then it successfully connects to imap server of YAHOO.

What i know "imaps" stands for "secure".

What i dont know is why I cant simply use "imap"?

Comment: Maybe Yahoo bans non-secure connections.

Comment: read the last answer of this post http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/imap-or-imaps-875240/

Comment: read the post..but it doesn't answer my question. I tried this" imap" for both yahoo and gmail server. If both have banned non-secure connection then there should be some documentation or blog about it.

Comment: If you go to the web pages for Yahoo or Gmail that tell how to set up your email client, they'll tell you which configuration to use (ports, SSL, etc.).  They won't tell you which configuration you **can't** use, but by implication they only support the ones they tell you about.

Comment: Yes, imaps is for secure connections.  It is rather awkward.  I wouldn't change the entire name of the class to describe one attribute of that class.  The props are all duplicated as well, such as prop.put("mail.imaps.timeout") vs prop.put("mail.imap.timeout")

Answer (score 5):

Google does require a secure connection.

https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018%2C1665144